# Disk usage by WIndows user

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I would like to report disk usage amount by user for a 30TB drive mounted on a Windows 2012 server. Is there a utility to help with this?

I'm aware of WinDirStat and similar tools that describe usage folder-by-folder, but I'm concerned with ownership in order to help inform a quota policy.

Comment: You likely would be able to generate this information using a Powershell script.  You can easily get the owernship of each file on a network share using Powershell.

Comment: Thanks, but how!!? :)

Comment: In order for me to answer that question I would have to write the script myself and that isn't going to happen